# Child DIV fill remaining height with scrollable content

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to set-up a menu `div A` with a content container `div B` below it. They are both nested inside a parent `div C`. When the content inside `div B` is higher than `div B` itself then a scroll bar needs to appear on `div B`.

[image: illustration of problem]
.

The main problem that I'm having is `div A` has an unknown height and can change at any time as content is added and removed at run-time via JavaScript and I would like `div B` to fill the remaining parent height while maintaining scrollability of its content.

I'm looking for a CSS only solution as the application I'm working on is already JS heavy and I wish to avoid adding more bloat.

A simplified version of my problem:
https://jsfiddle.net/uf3frdjv/

Comment: Could you please provide us the CSS and HTML code?

Comment: can you please make a fiddle? and copy your codes there ? so we've got some codes to play with ...

Comment: I'd love to but it's part of a large enterprise application so the actual html/css involved is crazy huge. I could make a simplified version of the problem if that helps?

Comment: @pra1998 yes please.

Comment: @NeophytePolyhistor https://jsfiddle.net/uf3frdjv/

Comment: @MaihanNijat https://jsfiddle.net/uf3frdjv/

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Using flexbox can solve your problem.

A simple example:

```
.C {
  display: flex; /* this enables flex layout */
  flex-direction: column; /* child divs are placed in column */
  height: 300px; /* Parent container must have a fixed height */
}
.A {
  flex: 0 0 auto; /* div A should remain its original height (neither expand nor shrink) */
}
.B {
  flex: 1 1 auto; /* div B should fit the remaining space */
  overflow-y: auto; /* enable scroll bar when div D exceeds div B's height */
}
```

For a live example, see this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ec8635ks/)

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, Thank you!

Comment: Thanks A LOT! I spent 4 hours trying to figure out how to do this, and you made it so simple. Awesome! However, height is required for `.C` so I've updated your answer. I've posted an improved version of this code below as an answer.

Comment: Just an addition: I had the same problem, but could not set a fixed size for the parent element (DIV C) because I wanted to fill the entire height of a mobile device. It worked for me with 'height: 100vh' instead of an exact pixel specification.

Answer (score 1):

This can also be achieved with CSS Grid which [now has more support](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-grid) than when this question was first asked and the syntax of which I find easier to understand than flexbox.

Using the example from @rhgb:

*HTML*

```
<div class="C">
  <div class="A"></div>
  <div class="B">
    <div class="D"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

*CSS*

```
.C {
  width: 100px;
  height: 300px;
  background: #ccc;

  display: grid;
  /* 
     Fix the first row's height to 100px and 
     fill the rest of the available space 
     with the second row: 
  */
  grid-template-rows: 100px 1fr;
}
.A {
  background: #999;
}
.B {
  background: #666;
  padding: 5px;
  overflow: auto;
}
.D {
  height: 400px;
  background: #333;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer by @rhgb is in the right direction, but it is missing a few properties like the fixed height being required on the parent, and also added some unneceesary properties such as the `flex` attributes.

Also, the bottom of `.B` was cut off in the fiddled linked to.

I have corrected the issues here:

```css
.C {

  height: 400px; /*  A fixed height on parent is required */
  display: flex; /* required */
  flex-direction: column; /* required */     
  background: #ccc;
  width: 300px;
}

.A {
  background: #ccc;
  padding: 0 20px;
}

.B {
  overflow: hidden; /* required */
  background: #227ddb;
  padding: 20px;
}

.D {

  overflow: auto; /* required */
  height: calc(100% - 20px); /* required - subtract the sum of padding-top and padding-bottom from .B, otherwise you lose the bottom of .B */
  padding: 10px;
  background: #eee;   
}
```

```html
<div class="C">
  <div class="A">
    <h1> Header</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="B">
    <div class="D">
      <div>
        Div D Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce tincidunt augue id tortor ultrices ultrices. Integer dictum lorem vel nunc ultrices, a dignissim arcu eleifend. Pellentesque in metus orci. Praesent pulvinar leo sed sodales aliquet.
        Etiam cursus nibh dolor, nec viverra magna luctus tincidunt. Nulla mollis finibus nisi eu viverra. Duis quis lorem et enim tempor scelerisque. Etiam vitae neque in ante blandit porta eget in massa. Sed fermentum at nisl ut convallis. Curabitur
        convallis dui in tortor hendrerit, sit amet lobortis tellus euismod. Vestibulum dui velit,yy rutrum sit amet neque et, bibendum interdum enim. Pellentesque orci ligula, viverra quis massa vel, ultrices auctor purus. Pellentesque scelerisque suscipit
        est in efficitur.

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've faced the exact same problem, but with a even more complex layout.

but if it can help anybody else in the future, here is how I did it:
https://jsfiddle.net/jtsknrLb/5/

In this example the vertical scrollbar doesn't overflow the parent as in the previous examples

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

div.c {
  width: 500px;
  height: 400px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: stretch;
  position: fixed;
}

div.a {
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
  padding: 12px;
  display: flex;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
}

div.b {
  display: flex;
  overflow: hidden;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
}

div.d {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  padding: 12px;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="c">
  <div class="a">
    some content
    <br>
    in the header
  </div>
  <div class="b">
    <div class="d">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
      tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
      quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
      consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
      cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
      proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

      <br>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
      tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
      quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
      consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
      cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
      proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

      <br><br>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
      tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
      quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
      consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
      cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
      proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can achieve it using combination of `display:flex` and `flex-direction: column;` set to the parent `div#C`, and `overflow-y:scroll` set to the bottom `div#B`.

You'd also set `height:100%` for `div#B` to fill the empty space when the sum of `div#A` and `div#B` heights is not enough to fill `div#C` height, just like this:

[**JS Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/Mi_Creativity/wt3octku/)

```css
#C {
  width: 300px;
  height: 400px;
  border: 2px solid tomato;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
#A { background-color:skyblue; }
#B { height:100%; background-color:orange; overflow-y:scroll; }
```

```html
<div id="C">
  <div id="A">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eligendi odit cumque animi cum recusandae reprehenderit labore incidunt necessitatibus. lorem</div>
  <div id="B">
    <div id="D">
      Dragée topping pastry cake liquorice. Oat cake cake dessert brownie caramels candy muffin. Jelly jelly beans gummies sugar plum oat cake.
      <br>
      <br>Fruitcake croissant candy canes gingerbread fruitcake brownie donut cookie. Donut gummi bears biscuit wafer ice cream sesame snaps. Tart ice cream biscuit jelly croissant candy. Marshmallow jelly tiramisu carrot cake apple pie cupcake dragée pudding
      lollipop.
      <br>Ice cream bear claw pastry powder danish. Oat cake chocolate cake sesame snaps topping bear claw caramels cake tiramisu. Icing muffin bonbon dragée sweet roll jujubes danish. Macaroon cake candy chupa chups bear claw chocolate bar muffin cookie.
      <br>
      <br>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Totam similique eligendi iste laudantium nisi eius velit odio dolores sit autem, quod corrupti quisquam tenetur doloribus, commodi obcaecati, fugit at nam?</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Resources:

- http://caniuse.com/#search=flex
- https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex

Comment: Thanks! That worked, however @rhgb solution went one step further and removed the scroll bar when the content wasn't tall enough. I absolutely love the food Lorem Ipsum you used. Where do you get it?

Comment: You welcome, yeah actually I liked the `overflow-y:auto` too, for such ipsum check http://www.cupcakeipsum.com/ and http://www.coffeeipsum.com/