# How to control with css, which child item should scroll within multiple div layers?

Tags: html, css

Going from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34668540/child-div-fill-remaining-height-with-scrollable-content), which already does exactly what I need (make a child fill remaining viewport size and scroll if it exceeds the remaining height), how can one extend the functionality with additional layers of `<div>`?

Here is some example code:

```css
.C {
  width: 300px;
  height: 100vh;
  background: #ccc;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.A {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  background: #999;
  height: 150px;
}
.B {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  background: #666;
  padding: 20px;

}
.D {
  height: 40rem;
  background: #333;
}

.X {
  background: green;
  padding: 25px;
}

.Y {
  background: red;
  padding: 25px;
}
```

```html
<div class="C">
  <div class="A"></div>
  <div class="B">
    <div class="X">
      <p>some x content</p>
    </div>
    <div class="Y" >
      <p>some y content</p>
    <div class="D"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

How can I make sure, `Y` will scroll if the the remaining viewport size is too small for the content `D`, instead of one of the parent containers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about giving `Y` class an `overflow-y: auto` and `max-height` ?

```css
.C {
  width: 300px;
  height: 100vh;
  background: #ccc;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.A {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  background: #999;
  height: 150px;
}
.B {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  background: #666;
  padding: 20px;

}
.D {
  height: 40rem;
  background: #333;
}

.X {
  background: green;
  padding: 25px;
}

.Y {
  background: red;
  padding: 25px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  max-height: 25vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="C">
  <div class="A"></div>
  <div class="B">
    <div class="X">
      <p>some x content</p>
    </div>
    <div class="Y" >
      <p>some y content</p>
    <div class="D"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Useful and concise.

Comment: Hmm, yes I guess I will have to solve it with some max-height properties.

Comment: The only problem with this is that depending on the height of the other content (`X`, `A`), I will end up with two scrollbars....

Comment: Well, If you only want 1 scrollbar to wrap all of that elements, then move the `overflow-y: auto` from `Y` to `C` and delete `max-height` from `Y`, so you will only have maximum 1 scrollbar for whatever height your `X`, `A`, and all elements inside C. But it will not meet the requirement of your problem which is scrollbar on `Y`